# Почему возникает ошибка: java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to Dancer

Tags: java

Скажите пожалуйста, почему когда я пытаюсь запустить данный пример происходит ошибка. Пример взят с сайта javarush.
**Ошибка возникает в строке , там где `for` в блоке декларации `Dancer d (Error:(16, 26) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to Dancer)`**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dancer dancer = new Dancer("Антон", 18);

        Dancer breakDanceDancer = new BreakDankDancer("Алексей", 19);// восходящее преобразование к базовому типу
        Dancer electricBoogieDancer = new ElectricBoogieDancer("Игорь", 20); // восходящее преобразование к базовому типу

        List discotheque = Arrays.asList(dancer, breakDanceDancer, electricBoogieDancer);

        for ( Dancer d : discotheque) {
            d.dance();// полиморфный вызов метода
        }
    }
}
```

Класс `Dancer` является родителем для `breakDanceDancer`  и `electricBoogieDancer`.

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, так как не имею дело с Java. У вас список каких типов? Object? Тогда в цикле используйте Object, а в вызове метода делайте приведение к типу Danser. Или, если возможно, то используйте List<Dancer>

Comment: Надо что-то такое List<Dancer>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, проблема в отсутствии дженериков.

[Подробнее](https://javarush.ru/quests/lectures/questsyntax.level07.lecture07)

По умолчанию(без указывания дженериков) в `List` хранятся объекты типа `Object`. Для прохода по листу вы в `foreach` создаете объект типа `Dancer`. Но он не знает, что в листе у вас объекты типа `Dancer`, и считает, что у вас там объекты типа `Object`. И он выводит ошибку, когда вы пишите `Dancer d : discotheque`, ему надо `Object d : discotheque`. Что бы указывать `Dancer` в `foreach`, используйте дженерики:

`List<Dancer> discotheque = Arrays.asList(dancer, breakDanceDancer, electricBoogieDancer);`.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ был очень полезен.

Comment: @Сергей пожалуйста, рад помочь